# Restsharp deserializing server side errors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, restsharp

Error handling RestSharp question.

If i have an error in request itself, server returns another Json answer, which should be desealized to another POCO object. Where i can handle this?

For example, normal answer:

```
{status: 100, message: { ** list of items ** }}
```

Error answer:

```
{status: 404, message: { ** error details ** }}
```

So, they are 2 different POCOs (though, can have one parent with status), so they should be parsed in different way (it would be perfect, if i'd be able to read status, and select how to deserialize result).

I'm using RestSharp with wp7 async library, so i see the request as

```
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<NormalPOCO, ErrorPOCO>(request);
```

but where can i override deserialization itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with RestSharp, though it doesn't support this kind of conditional deserialization.

```
class StatusPOCO { public int Status { get; set; } }
class NormalPOCO : StatusPOCO { ... }
class ErrorPOCO : StatusPOCO { ... }

var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<StatusPOCO>(request);
// restsharp's deserializer:
IDeserializer deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
if (response.Data.status != 100)
   error = deserializer.Deserialize<ErrorPOCO>(response);
else
   normal = deserializer.Deserialize<NormalPOCO>(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with sending manual request via HttpWebRequest + using async and Json.net. It is looking like this

```
        var stringResult = await productSearchDataService.LaunchSearchAsync(name, label); // Sends HttpWebRequest
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringResult )) { return; }     // TODO: notify no internet
        var status = (int)JObject.Parse(stringResult)["status"];            
        if (status != 100) { return; }            // TODO: notify some shit happened
        try
        {
            private var parsedResult = await TaskEx.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NormalAnswerPoco>(stringResult));

        ***
        }
```